# How to render an ordered dictionary in django templates?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm trying to learning django templates but it's not easy.
I have a certain views.py containing a dictionary to be rendered with a template. The dictionary is made of key-value pairs, where key are unique names and values are some values associated to those names. I render the dictionary in the following way:

```
return render_to_response('results.html', {'data': results_dict})
```

Now my problem is that in my template I need to display the names in alphabetical (or ASCIIbetical) order with the relatives values.
Actually in my template I have:

```
<table>
{% for key, value in data.items %}
    <tr>
        <td> {{ key }}: </td> <td> {{ value }} </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can I render the data in sorted way?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

In views.py (Python2):

```
return render_to_response('results.html',
    {'data': sorted(results_dict.iteritems())})
```

Or in views.py (Python3):

```
return render_to_response('results.html',
    {'data': sorted(results_dict.items())})
```

In template file:

```
{% for key, value in data.items() %}
    <tr>
        <td> {{ key }}: </td> <td> {{ value }} </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: {% for key, value in data.items() %} thisd does not work in Django template

Comment: @MukeshKumar - need to avoid () when we use functions in django templates so need to use just 'data.items'

Answer (score 29):

Although changing the code in the view is preferable, you could also use the dictsort template tag:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-dictsort

```
<table>
{% for key, value in data.items|dictsort:"0.lower" %}
    <tr>
        <td> {{ key }}: </td> <td> {{ value }} </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: great answer. Worth mentioning that we can use [dictsortreverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#dictsortreversed) as well to sort in reverse order.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for this - works perfectly. I almost discovered this but got stuck trying `dictsort:0` (i.e. no quotes on the 0), due to the final example [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#dictsort). Can anyone explain that point in the docs?

Answer (score 16):

Another solution that worked very well for me and I think it's simplier. It uses `OrderedDict()` [more info](http://pymotw.com/2/collections/ordereddict.html)

In your `views.py` file add:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
def main(request):
    ord_dict = OrderedDict()
    ord_dict['2015-06-20'] = {}
    ord_dict['2015-06-20']['a'] = '1'
    ord_dict['2015-06-20']['b'] = '2'
    ord_dict['2015-06-21'] = {}
    ord_dict['2015-06-21']['a'] = '10'
    ord_dict['2015-06-21']['b'] = '20'
    return render(request, 'main.html', {'context': ord_dict})
```

Then in your template, you can do:

```
<table>
{% for key, value in context.items %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ key }}</td>
        <td>{{ value.a }}</td>
        <td>{{ value.b }} </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

This will return the keys of the dictionary in the same ordered that they were put in.

```
2015-06-20  1   2
2015-06-21  10  20
```

Comment: Works.  Would be nice to do this all inside of the `OrderedDict()` call

Answer (score 8):

Refreshing old question but it was something that I've spent some time on as a programming noobie.
It kinds of expands Yuji Tomita's answer.

How to sort dictionary that looks like this:

```
{model_A_object: {key: value, ...},...}
```

by model_A_object.field.

I fill it with for loop, and use it to store some aggregation, etc.,  data for queryset that I pass to template.

I've managed to do this (with Shubuntu from #Django help) by:

```
    result = sorted(dictionary.iteritems(), key= lambda (k, v) :  (k.field, v))
```

Then in the template:

```
    {% for model_A_object, data in result %}
        {% for key, value in data.items %}
            ...
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Clean and easy, yet not that simple to figure out for beginner. Notice, that first for loop has **result** not **result.items** as it's not dictionary anymore, but list of tuples.

Hope it helps someone.