# Ordering dictionary in context Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, dictionary

I looked at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250276/how-to-render-an-ordered-dictionary-in-django-templateshttp://), with an example of sorting dictionaries.

I have a dictionary of programme objects where the key is a programme object and the value is a lookup of the number of related Project objects.

```
def DepartmentDetail(request, pk):
    department = Department.objects.get(pk=pk)
    programmes = Programme.objects.all().filter(department=department).exclude(active=False).order_by('long_name')
    combi = {}
    for p in programmes:
        prj = Project.objects.all().filter(programme=p)
        combi[p] = str(len(prj))
    return render(request, 'sysadmin/department.html',{'department': department, 'programmes': programmes, 'combi': sorted(combi.items())})
```

In the model, Programme returns a string 'long_name', so I believe that I am trying to sort a string key and a string value.

In the template I get to the keys and values as so,

```
{% for programme, n in combi %}
```

This gives me the error..

```
unorderable types: Programme() < Programme()
```

I don't really understand the error, in the [python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) it states that the sorted() method accepts any iterable - So why does this happen?

I'm looking at collections.OrderedDict to solve the problem, but I want to know why this doesn't work.

Thanx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Databases with index on columns are really good at sorting. There's almost never a need to sort on the client side. You can almost always do it in the server. The funny part it you apparently know how to do it too.

```
 ....exclude(active=False).order_by('long_name')  # <--- this
```

Guess what, your data is already sorted there isn't a need to sort it again inside python!!

But there is a much bigger issue in your code. You are fetching a set of `Project` items and then looping through that set to retrieve them all over again one by one. So if you have 200 `Project` items you are doing 200 queries when one query does the job just as well. Just add [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) or [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.prefetch_related) depending on which direction you have the relationship.

Your code ideally should be something like this

```
department = Department.objects.get(pk=pk)
    programmes = Programme.objects.all().filter(department=department).exclude(active=False).order_by('long_name')
    return render(request, 'sysadmin/department.html',{'department': department, 'programmes': programmes,})
```

As far as I can see combi just contains duplicated data. The same thing can be accessed from `programmes` eg. `programme.project_set.all()`
(again this depends on which direction you have the relationship, your models are not shown)

Recommended reading: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey

Comment: I am looking up related Projects server side (as it's the only way I can think of), are you suggesting that I do it client side? If so what would be the correct way to do that?

Comment: Was just looking at what the combi values actually are and it would seem like adding an `annotate(project_count=Count('project'))` would be required

Comment: Although I do read the django docs, I was told to do lookups in the view as much as possible instead of using things like set_all() in templates. I am also unsure as to how _set.all() does it's work. It would appear that all the related objects and their fields are passed to the template, always - is this the case?

Comment: yes there's no harm in doing _set.all() in the template. All related objects are passed automatically to the template provided you have used select_related (or prefetch_related as the case maybe)

Comment: Thanks for this. I believe it's prefetch_related for reverse foreign key relationships as projects have a foreign key to programmes.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `sorted` expects a way to be able to order the items and by default there isn't any way to know how to order your *objects*. You can provide a key

```
sorted(combi.items(), key=lambda i: i.long_name)
```

Comment: Whilst this may fix the "unorderable types" error, you should use [e4c5's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41586684/1324033)